# 2 Navigation Drawer Activities In the Same Project

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation

First I created a new project called Recipes(example) and in this I created my first Activity as a Navigation Drawer Activity, and from the default tags in it(gallery,camera,etc) I changed them to what I required.
On running this it worked perfectly.
Then I needed to create my second Activity, I created another Navigation Drawer Activity. On clicking a button from the navigation drawer activity of the first activity it went to the second one. But to my surprise the navigation drawer didnt work on the second activity.
Please help me out.
Thanks                                                                                Kalyan

Comment: Please post your code. We cannot guess stuff.

Comment: Um which file's code do you want?